# Debugging an angularjs Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way we can Debug angularjs Application? I know it can be done using Chrome webDeveloper console or Add-on like firebug.
The problem I face during debugging there is that it goes to the **angular.js** file and keep on executing there for a long time which takes a lot of time to come back to my original file where I have put breakpoint.
Is there any way I could skip my library files and only concentrate on my source file or does any IDE supports this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could give a try to [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) in Google Chrome. It could help you a bit.

Comment: I have tried it.But I am expecting something like stackTrace.